# Page 404 Error on Localhost

Tags: 404-error, localhost, xampp

I am currently working on my localhost and the problem is that all the wordpress related urls would direct me to error 404 page not found but somehow i can still access my website which still functions quite well (but i cannot access wordpress related things such as dashboard, themes and settings). I've tried many solutions on the internet such as editing loadmodule rewrite and allowoverride in apache httpd.conf (i use XAMPP) which should work but it still doesn't. My .htaccess file is still there and i have tried shifting lines up and down but it doesn't work. How can i regain access to wordpress? I am freaking out :(

Answer (score 0):

In some instances (tried everything counts) I've had to (be sure I had a current xml export of the content + ftp back up of the wp-content dir + copy paste your customized CSS and other code) wipe the site, fresh install WP install all the plugins, theme, etc then import the xml and/or copy the wp-content dir back to the site. 
I'm sure there's many fixes out there, but from experience I've found a simple wipe and re-set-up often saves so much time.